# Inserting Javascript Variables into a flashVars string

Tags: javascript, html, video, flashvars

I am using camendesign's [VIDEO FOR EVERYBODY](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody) script to embed a video element on my page, and have a flash player fallback for those who do not have HTML5 functionality.

But I am changing al the URLs to be dynamically loaded when the page is called.  Everything is parsing out fine except for the flashVars string in the object embed params tag. The value of this params tag needs to be URL Encoded, so I have a bit of javascript before the video is rendered on the page to encode the url for the poster image AND the video file using the values that are loaded in.

My question is this: How do I properly have the two values parse out so that they complete the flashVars value properly?

Here's my code: (consequently, this is a Java site I'm running, hence the JAVA c:sets)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<c:set var="title" value="Blender Demo Reel 2013"/>
<c:set var="file" value="bdr2013"/>
<c:set var="poster" value="poster.jpg"/>
<c:set var="width" value="960"/>
<c:set var="height" value="540"/>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>New Video Player</title>
</head>

<script>
    var posterEncode = encodeURIComponent("${poster}");
    var fileEncode = encodeURIComponent("${file}");
</script>

<body>

<div id="videoContainer">
    <video controls preload poster="${poster}" width="${width}" height="${height}">
        <source src="${file}.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="${file}.ogv" type="video/ogg">
        <source src="${file}.webm" type="video/webm">
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf" width="${width}" height="${height}">
            <param name="movie" value="http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf" />
            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
            <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
            <param name="flashVars" value="controlbar=over&amp;image="+posterEncode+"&amp;file="+fileEncode+".mp4" />
            <img alt="Big Buck Bunny" src="${poster}" width="${width}" height="${height}" title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />
        </object>
    </video>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The source code when I view this in a browser comes back as this:

```
<script>
    var posterEncode = encodeURIComponent("poster.jpg");
    var fileEncode = encodeURIComponent("bdr2013");
</script>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>New Video Player</title>
<body>

<div id="videoContainer">
    <video controls preload poster="poster.jpg" width="960" height="540">
        <source src="bdr2013.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="bdr2013.ogv" type="video/ogg">
        <source src="bdr2013.webm" type="video/webm">
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf" width="960" height="540">
            <param name="movie" value="http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf" />
            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
            <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
            <param name="flashVars" value="controlbar=over&amp;image="+posterEncode+"&amp;file="+fileEncode+".mp4" />
            <img alt="Big Buck Bunny" src="poster.jpg" width="960" height="540" title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />
        </object>
    </video>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you do the URI encoding of `poster` and `file` in Java on the server side instead?

Comment: But wouldn't I still have to insert those variables into the flashVars string? And that's what I am asking in the above question.

Answer (score 0):

You're just writing out HTML attributes. There's no need for JavaScript here. URI encode the strings in Java and put them in Java variables and then put them in your HTML just like you do with any other Java variable:

```
<param name="flashVars" value="controlbar=over&amp;image=${posterEncoded}&amp;file=${fileEncoded}.mp4" />
```

Comment: But then I would need a second set of variables for the video source tags, wouldn't I?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but the larger answer is: If you just need to get values into HTML tags once, then do it on the server side. If you need values to change dynamically in the browser in response to user actions, you might need JavaScript, but otherwise just do it in Java.

Comment: What I'm looking to do is call all the data once, encode it (if needed) and then plug it into the places where it needs to go.  the difference between the video source src value and the flashvars file value is that the flashVars value need to be URL Encoded, the video source src value does not. So if there is a way to bring all of the data on this page, then place it where it needs to  be, and in the format it needs to be in once would be ideal.

Comment: Then yes, you'll need a second set of variables.

Answer (score 0):

HUZZAH!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<c:set var="title" value="Blender Demo Reel 2013"/>
<c:set var="file" value="bdr2013"/>
<c:set var="poster" value="poster.jpg"/>
<c:set var="width" value="960"/>
<c:set var="height" value="540"/>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>New Video Player</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="videoContainer">
    <video controls preload poster="${poster}" width="${width}" height="${height}">
        <source src="${file}.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="${file}.ogv" type="video/ogg">
        <source src="${file}.webm" type="video/webm">
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf" width="${width}" height="${height}">
            <param name="movie" value="http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf" />
            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
            <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
            <script>
                var posterEncode = encodeURIComponent("${poster}");
                var fileEncode = encodeURIComponent("${file}");
                document.write("<param name='flashVars' value='controlbar=over&amp;image="+posterEncode+"&amp;file="+fileEncode+".mp4' />");
            </script>
            <img alt="${title}" src="${poster}" width="${width}" height="${height}" title="${title}" />
        </object>
    </video>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I threw the javascript encodeURIComponent function and a document.write into where I need the dynamic param line to be, and SHAZAM! worked like a charm.